# How get space separated double array from a gui in MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Hi I have a Matlab GUI which takes space separated array(double or integer) and when the GUI button clicked i need to pass these data in to another separate .m file within the same directory. In the button_cal_Callback I try to retrieve data.

```
function button_cal_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

I tried several ways but i fail following codes are my attempts. S is the new variable i created to assign data and edit_S is the edit text label tag value.

```
S = guidata(handles.edit_S,'array');
S = get(hObject,'edit_S');
S = str2double(get(handles.edit_S,'string'));
```

Non of the above codes work for me some one kindly let me know how to get this values from front end...

example values entered>> S = 1638 1500 1688 1688 1688 1688 1688 1713 1738 1763 1788 1819
How it should pass to the 2nd M file>> [1638 1500 1688 1688 1688 1688 1688 1713 1738 1763 1788 1819]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thusharaK - I'll try to describe why each of the above attempts doesn't really do what you want.

```
S = guidata(handles.edit_S,'array');
```

Check the documentation for [guidata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).  This function is used to only get or set (update) the handles structure with user-defined GUI data.  By default, *handles* includes all of the handles to the GUI widgets, plus any data that you decide to add.  The above line of code is an attempt to save the string 'array' using the edit text widget's handle.  This will actually overwrite all *handles* data!

```
S = get(hObject,'edit_S');
```

Here, *hObject* is the button handle and so has nothing to do with the edit text widget. *get(hObject,'someField')* gets the someField attribute from hObject.  If it doesn't exist, like in this case, then an error is generated.

```
S = str2double(get(handles.edit_S,'string'));
```

This is almost what you want.  Using the *edit_S* handle, you are trying to get the *String* data associated with i.e. that text written in the text edit widget.  But it is probably returned as a cell, so you must do the conversion from a cell array to a character array before the *str2num* (or *str2double*)

```
numericData = str2num(char(get(handles.edit_S,'string')));
```

This should produce the array of values that you can now pass to the next function.  Try this and see what happens!